# Putty Shift arrows

Tags: c, emacs, keyboard, terminal, putty

I want to make Putty recognize shift arrow sequences

as i know for example ^[[A means up and ^[[1;2A is shift+up

I've modified putty source code as following

```
            if (shift_state == 1)
                if (app_flg)
                    p += sprintf((char *) p, "\x1BO1;2%c", xkey);
                else
                    p += sprintf((char *) p, "\x1B[1;2%c", xkey);
            else
                if (app_flg)
                    p += sprintf((char *) p, "\x1BO%c", xkey);
                else
                    p += sprintf((char *) p, "\x1B[%c", xkey);
```

instead of

```
                    if (app_flg)
                        p += sprintf((char *) p, "\x1BO%c", xkey);
                    else
                        p += sprintf((char *) p, "\x1B[%c", xkey);
```

by running cat -vt putty seams to provide correct key code to terminal but in emacs i still can't shift select text (instead it puts text ;2A for up etc.)

running begPutty which already contains this fix (also i don't have source code for it) cat -vt prints the same key codes when using shift arrows and works fine in emacs.

Basically i want to implement begPutty functionality fixes for keycodes but i don't have it's source code

Comment: I'm trying this code and it doesn't compile because shift_state is not declared anywhere. Could you post a patch or the code to the final solution? I made this changes in TERMINAL.C, line 5898. Thank you.

Comment: @adeandrade look at this https://github.com/troydm/putty-modified. this repo contains modified TERMINAL.c and WINDOW.c for 0.61 version. And already compiled exe file that you can try out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added emacs as a tag as my opinion is that the problem is in emacs not recognizing your escape sequence and not in your modification of putty.

Could you try with

```
(define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;2A" [S-up])
```

in your .emacs, relaunch emacs, press shift up and then CTRL-H L.  Emacs should then show you how it interpreted your key press.

Comment: yes but why begPutty works fine then if emacs is at fault? I've tried that one you mentioned but it still prints ;2A instead of shift selecting text

Comment: you usually want to define low level stuff like that in the `input-decode-map` (or `function-key-map` in older emacs versions).

Comment: What does emacs print when you type CTRL-H L (that should open a window -- emacs term, you can call it a pane -- with a textual representation of the uninterpreted input, it will clearly indicates if you have to work on putty or on emacs).

Comment: @jtahlborn, input-decode-map seems new since the last time I worked on this.  It's description implies that it is better for the purpose than key-translation-map.

Comment: that did it CTRL-H L helped me alot thx, the problem was that app_flg was always on when shift_code was 1, removed that line and it works fine

Answer (score 6):

The answer is kitty (KiTTY is a fork from version 0.66 of PuTTY) guys ! My whole life has been a lie : D

http://www.9bis.net/kitty/?page=Download

It has fixed shift+arrow keys bug delivered with putty (also shift+arrow keys was not working in other ssh clients)

After kitty I downloaded sanos editor from here http://www.jbox.dk/sanos/editor.htm

Sanos editor comes like 1 file and is compiled like this:

```
wget http://www.jbox.dk/downloads/edit.c
gcc -o edit edit.c -Os
./edit edit.c
```

The only problem with sanos is the buffer is lost once you quit, but you can open many files at once and navigate through the tabs using ctrl+tab also press ctry+y for keymapping help

[image]